# Are there some US presidents who didn't play golf before being elected but started aftward?

Tags: united-states, president, public-image

I'm basically asking how strong of a presidential tradition playing golf has become in the US. One way to quantify this issue is to ask: are there presidents who didn't play golf before being electected POTUS but started to play while in office?

Since playing golf at all (rather than well) requires little in the way of prior preparation, one could say that almost anyone played golf at some point in their lives. So, I suppose a sharper way to ask this question that side-steps that issue is to ask: are there presidents who played significantly more golf in office than before they were elected?

(I should note that in [some discourses](https://www.sbnation.com/golf/2017/3/27/15073086/donald-trump-tweets-barack-obama-golf) (and in [more than one](https://qz.com/1552736/after-declaring-a-national-emergency-trump-spent-the-weekend-at-his-golf-course/)) US presidents "playing golf" has been used to stand for "wasting time". So I think it's interesting to ask the question whether some presidents picked it up while being president, i.e. whether this specific "time waster", playing golf, has some kind of traditional aspect for the presidency by now.)

Comment: I was going to guess  Obama, but apparently he started playing in 1997: https://www.golfdigest.com/story/obamaswing

Answer (score 4):

The "President Golfs" is a recent trope image of the United States President.  We are currently in the longest stretch of golfing POTUS' in U.S. History, with every President from Eisenhower to Trump (1953-present) having played at least one round in office (The golfer's with the least games are President George W. Bush, who gave it up after the war in Iraq was declared in a move for solidarity with the troops and having a faux pas of following strong comments to the press on terrorism with the statement "Watch this Drive".  Kennedy was secretive about his golfing habits, as he was very critical of Eisenhower's golfing habits (the man played the second most rounds of golf of any President, with Woodrow Wilson being the undisputed golf king... er... president, playing twice that of Eisenhower), George H.W. Bush was inducted into the golfing Hall of Fame, and his presidential son came to the defense of Obama against fellow Republican critics... It also explains the much noted Bush, Clinton, Obama family friendships as all four men loved the sport.

Lyndon Johnson was probably the most political on the course, and negotiated a lot of laws during his frequent golf games, which he frequently invited political rivals to take it to the green with him and was known to have a rather bad game, making it known to all that he was doing this for the wheeling and dealing and the game was supposed to be friendly (Johnson's favorite hobby is probably making people uncomfortable for his own amusement.   He would frequently ask staffers to continue buisness in the bathroom while Johnson tended to more pressing buisness... and that's why "Johnson" is a Euphamism for male genitalia and was a closeted Aquacar fanboy... and by closeted I mean he would frequently invite people for a ride in his "car" on his Texas Ranch, and come out of the closet by loudly announcing to his passenger the breaks had been cut while speeding towards a lake.).

I  do recall that Obama took to golf much more after his election to President, but I don't have specific citation to say for sure.  What's more common are Presidents who were fans of the game prior to their Presidency, but gave it up or played less (Bush and Kennedy, and tragically FDR, who played a lot before he was crippled by polio.  He's the only known golfer who never played in office.).

One case that may qualify is Nixon, who had played before his presidency but never before his Vice-Presidency.   But when your number two to the second most profalific golfing President (Eisenhower) you pick up the sport quickly.  During Nixon's presidency, he did golf, but it was clearly for buisness and politics.  His true sport of fashion was bowling, and he installled a bowling lane in the White House and was known to bowl alone and bizarrely in his suit and tie.  His love of both was emphasized in this popular Washington Joke:

> “I shot a 128 today,” Nixon announces.
>
> “Your golf game is getting better,” Henry Kissinger tells him.
>
> “I was bowling, Henry.”

President Taft was the first President to play a game during his presidency, prior to Esinhower, presidents who played (but have yet to be mentioned) included Warren Harding (first to have a course named in his honor) and Calvin Coolidge (though his Hobbies were more well known to be clay pidgeon shooting and napping.  He played purely for optics.).

Though it's widely accepted fact that the most athletic President was Teddy Roosevelt, who would prefer game hunting (to such a degree that he created The National Park system specifically to prevent himself from killing everything), swimming, jogging, answering army officers letters of complaint about the amount of time they were expected to ride a horse in training (by way of riding a horse four times longer than was required to show the poor officer he was complaining to the wrong commander in chief), and stilt walking... and then whacking people with them when they didn't listen to the "speak softly" parts of his requests.

Other presidents were well known for odd hobbies.  FDR was an avid stamp collector and there wasn't a day in his presidency where he didn't look at his collection and would frequently send designs for new stamps to the Postmaster General.   Thomas Jefferson was a paleontology hobbiest and got obsessed with the American Mastodon, going so far as to assemble a skeloton of one in the White House, like a long term Jigsaw puzzlist would do.   Perhapes the most bizzare was John Quincy Adams, who was a herpetologist, had one of the most extensive collection of presidential pets and his prized pet alligator was shown to everyone who visited him (or just his political rivals... he was well aware of the implication of asking a political rival if he wanted to help "Feed his alligator".  He was also known for the most bizarre sport practiced by a sitting President.  Every morning in the spring and summer, he would start the day by a nice, brisk, 6 AM skinny dip in the Potomac river (one assumes he had his back to congress to further his point, when the alligator didn't work.).